# Could something akin to Cyanobacteria evolve on earth today or are all available niches taken for different kind of life to come to be?

Tags: life

The most basic form of my question would have to be: could ***new*** life form from molecules as happened with the first life on earth, here on earth? If not why not?

Comment: Are you asking about abiogenesis? There are many similar questions here, check the 'related' list or the tag [tag:abiogenesis]

Comment: It seems that [this Question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64302/%E2%80%A6) answers my question.